# useContext is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I have a problem with useContext because it returns undefined to me. could you please help me?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'course' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to use `useContext(courseGlobal)` not the `ContextCourse` which is actually your `Provider`, not your `Context`

Answer (score 1):

`courseGlobal` is your context. you should pass courseGlobal to `useContext` but you are passing `ContextCourse` that is a provider not a context